# Binding ContextMenu to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a bit of a problem binding a ContextMenu that resides inside a Popup to a DataGrid.
Basically, I want the ContextMenu to appear on Right-Click on any DataGridTextColumn, and be able to edit the text inside.

This is the code (shortened):

```
<Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="Edit_Or_Delete_Popup">
        <RichTextBox x:Name="Edit_Or_Delete">
            <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="Edit_Or_Delete_Context">
                    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="Edit_Click"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Popup>

    <DataGrid MouseRightButtonDown="Right_Mouse_Click">
        <DataGridTextColumn>....
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In the XAML code:

```
private void Right_Mouse_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Edit_Or_Delete_Context.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

However for some reason, the focus is pointed to the popup, and leaves the DataGrid.
What I want is to be able to edit the text in an EditWindow of some sort, and then use the DataGrid Column information to update a database with the new information.

Can it be done?